# Embed IPE drawing in latex with proper size

Tags: fontsize, draw, ipe

I have a drawing I made in IPE and exported to eps to import it into my latex document. My drawing contains a lot of text and math. I would like this text to appear as the same size as the text in the rest of the document. However, if I include the drawing without scaling the text appears much to large. Is there a way to configure IPE to output text with the correct size?